# Couldn't match expected type error

Tags: haskell

As a beginner, I was working on item number 3 of the Haskell 99 problems. The first code snippet is my solution. However, I cannot add the type declaration of `[a] -> Int -> a`.

It produces an error: `Couldn't match type 'a' with 'Int'`

```
--My Solution
--elementAt :: [a] -> Int -> a
elementAt xs num = head . reverse $ takeWhile (<num+1) xs
```

Meanwhile, one of the solution in the problem 3 works perfectly with the same output.

```
elementAt' :: [a] -> Int -> a
elementAt' list i = list !! (i - 1)
```

I've used the `:type` in the GHCI for the `elementAt` without the declaration and it shows:

```
elementAt :: (Num c, Ord c) => [c] -> c -> c
```

What is the difference of the two functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`takeWhile (<num+1) xs` says that you want to take elements at the front of the list `xs` while the *element* (not the index!) is less than `num + 1`. Since you're comparing `num` (which is an Int) with the list elements, the compiler infers that the list elements have to be `Int` as well, which contradicts your type declaration.

Without the type declaration, GHC infers that `xs`'s elements and `num` have to be the same type (since you compare list elements with num). This type has to have an `Ord` instance (for the comparison) as well as a `Num` instance (because of the addition).

Answer (score 1):

The type of `takeWhile (< num + 1)` is `[Int] -> [Int]`.

However the type of `xs` is `[a]`.

Essentially you are trying to apply a predicate `Int -> Bool` to elements of type `a`.

If you want to filter based on the position in the list, you first need to augment the input list with the position of each element. You can do this fairly easily with `zip`:

```
zip xs [1..]
```

You can then drop elements based on the value of the second element of the resulting list.